# person and saving books

Tags: cocoa, core-data, swift3

i searching for the "best-way" to realize the following situation:

- I working with swift 3 for osx

left side: all my persons from core data in a table view.

if so select a person:

- middle will shown a new empty table view
- right side will shown all books from core data in a table view.

now you can drag and drop the books from right side to the middle empty table view. and here is the question.

how will i solve this situation?

should I insert a new object every time if I drag a book from right to middle table view and save the context later, if the user pressed the button "Save"

```
let appdelegate = NSApplication.shared().delegate as! AppDelegate
let context = appdelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
let newBook = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Books", into:context) as! Books
newBook.name = "xxx"
newBook.category = "yyy"
```

or is there an better way to manage this situation?
i hope you understand my "problem" :)

Comment: Does the middle table view show the persons books? Do you want to duplicate the dragged book or do you want to add the dragged book to the relationship?

Comment: yes, the middle table view will shows the books, which i will new assign to the selected person. i would like to duplicate

Comment: Yes, you have to insert a new object.

Comment: okay, is this the best way to do this?